# A complex recurrence relation

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursion, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I wanted to find a recurrence formula for

$(1, 1497), (2, 1585), (3, 1587), (4, 1675), (5, 1677), (6, 1765), (7, 
  1767), (8, 1855), (9, 1857), (10, 1945), (11, 1947), (12, 
  1997), (13, 2494), (14, 2496), (15, 2584), (16, 2586), (17, 
  2674), (18, 2676), (19, 2764), (20, 2766), (21, 2854), (22, 
  2856), (23, 2944), (24, 2946), (25, 2996), (26, 3493)$

I don't know what should be added for jump between eleven and twelve term.

The formula I've got looks like this

$F_{n} = 1495 + \frac{1}{2} (90 n + 43 (-1)^n - 43) + 497 \left \lfloor \frac{n}{14} \right \rfloor$

How the recurrence formula should look like?

Comment: See [Lychrel numbers](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LychrelNumber.html) and links therein. Btw, what you posted is not a recurrence relation.

Comment: @dxiv has already identified the numbers, but for future reference: Please include the context in which such mystery sequences arise. Otherwise, "find the pattern" questions tend to be exercises in mind-reading, not mathematics, and so tend to be poorly received on Math.SE. (That said, most "find the pattern" questions have a meager half-dozen or so terms; the twenty-six offered here are a welcome change.) Also, a good resource for this is the searchable [Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences (OEIS.org)](http://oeis.org); your numbers appear in sequence [A023108](http://oeis.org/A023108).